# CountDown timer PHP/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

[image]Hi I have a JavaScript for countdown which is selecting time form MySQL and it is working fine on (Chrome, Firefox), but on (IE and Safari) it is returning "NaNd NaNh NaNm NaNs".

I have attached my code below.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "timer") or die("Error Could 
not connect to the database Sir." . mysqli_error($con));

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM counter WHERE id = 1") or 
die(mysqli_error($con));
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)or die(mysqli_error($con));



?>
<div id="form<?php echo $row['id'];?>" style="color:green" class="form-
group">                      
</div>


<Script>
function createCountDown(elementId, date){
console.log(date);
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date(date).getTime();
console.log(countDownDate);

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function(){

// Get todays date and time


var now = new Date().getTime();

// Find the distance between now an the count down date
var distance = (countDownDate) - (now);

//Hint on converting from object to the string.
//var distance = Date.parse(countDownDate) - Date.parse(now);

// Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
//console.log(days);
var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 *
                                                             60));
var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

// Display the result in the element with id="demo"
document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

// If the count down is finished, write some text
if (distance < 0)
{
  clearInterval(x);
  document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = "ORDER EXPIRED";
}
}, 1000);
}
createCountDown("form<?php echo $row['id'];?>", "<?php echo 
$row['time_to_expire'] ;?>")
</Script>
```

Please check if i am missing something again. thank you for all the replies.

Comment: try this `createCountDown("form<?php echo $row['id'];?>", "<?php echo
                $row['time_to_expire'] ;?>")` you are using single quote `'form<?php echo $row['id'];?>'`

Comment: That is NOT a matter or quote use. I [reproduced the issue](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/NvZXEg).

Comment: Thank you for the replies but I have tried inserting the quote it doesn't work as  @LouysPatriceBessette has mentioned.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Still the quotes are not valid and have to be fixed.

Comment: Yes... I have to admit... It is about quote. Remove the quote around `"<?php echo
                $row['time_to_expire'] ;?>"` because that has to be an integer (will be passed to `Date()` an IE do not digest string on that. [Issue fixed here](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/EvBQjz?editors=1111) But that wasn't a single/double combinaison issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

## Internet Explorer and Safari aren't tolerant on malformed dates.

The date passed from PHP to JavaScript [`Date()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) : `2017-09-30 00:00:00` was *"malformed"*.
It came from PHP `Date("Y-m-d H:i:s");` which is VERY commonly used...

The fix on JavaScript side is: `date = date.replace(" ","T");`

It also could be fixed on PHP side with: `$date = Date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s");`
Or if the date comes form a database:

```
$date = str_replace(" ","T",$row['time_to_expire']);
createCountDown("form<?php echo $row['id'];?>", "<?php $date;?>")
```

The resulting date string is then `2017-09-30T00:00:00`, which is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) compliant.

**The issue was abvout ONE character!**
*I'll remember that one.*
;)

Comment: If it isn't solving the issue... (I suddenly have a doubt) Please add `console.log(date);` right under `function createCountDown(elementId, date){` and `console.log(countDownDate);` right under `var countDownDate = new Date(date).getTime();`.

Comment: Hi guys I have tried all the solutions that you have provided and they are still not working, i have tried to add as #LouysPatriceBessette and it doesn't make a different and i have tried #user2486 still the same and #yogesh patel doesn't work. please if  there is anything i am missing tell me i have updated the post with my latest code. Thanks

Comment: Tell me what's the output of your console logs... As I asked previously. That will help me.

Comment: this is the output of my console 1506722400000

Comment: But, can you tell me what is `$row['time_to_expire']` ? Or the result of the 1st console.log?

Comment: the results of the first log is 2017-09-30 00:00:00

Comment: mmm... And it doesn't work? I just replaced your PHP by `4567` for the id... And your `time to expire`. And.... It works in Firefox. Try it : [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/EvBQEa?editors=1010)

Comment: Chrome and FIrefox work but IE and Safari are returning this: NaNd NaNh NaNm NaNs

Comment: lol... @LouysPatriceBessette why are you laughing, I have attached a picture on the post for IE. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153929/discussion-between-fulufhelo-praise-munyai-and-louys-patrice-bessette).

Answer (score 2):

Check carefully `'` single quotes here, Use double quotes for first parameter as second param.

```
createCountDown("form<?php echo $row['id'];?>", "<?php echo $row['time_to_expire'] ;?>")
```

Here is working example

```js
function createCountDown(elementId, date) 
    {
    // Set the date we're counting down to
    var countDownDate = new Date(date).getTime();
    //console.log(countDownDate.getTime());
    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function() 
    {

      // Get todays date and time


      var now = new Date().getTime();

      // Find the distance between now an the count down date
      var distance = (countDownDate) - (now);

      //Hint on converting from object to the string.
      //var distance = Date.parse(countDownDate) - Date.parse(now);

      // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
      var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 
      60));
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

      // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
      document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
      + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

      // If the count down is finished, write some text 
      if (distance < 0) 
      {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = "ORDER EXPIRED";
      }
      }, 1000);
      }
      createCountDown('form1', "08-09-2017 12:10:00Z");
      createCountDown('form2', "08-09-2018 12:10:00Z");
```

```html
<div id="form1"></div>
<div id="form2"></div>
```

Comment: Just to mention that even if this advise is good, the PHP is executed long before the JS, so in this case, there was absolutely no quote issue. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) and try below code for timer

```
    var eventTime = moment("target time").unix(),
                currentTime = moment().unix(),
                diffTime = eventTime - currentTime,
                duration = moment.duration(diffTime * 1000, "milliseconds"),
                interval = 1000;

            if (diffTime > 0) {
                var timer = setInterval(function () {
                    duration = moment.duration(duration.asMilliseconds() - interval, 'milliseconds');
                    var h = moment.duration(duration).hours(),
                        m = moment.duration(duration).minutes(),
                        s = moment.duration(duration).seconds();

                    // show how many hours, minutes and seconds are left
                    var temp = '<div><span>' + h + '</span> hr </div> <div><span>'
                        + m + '</span> min </div> <div><span>' + s +
                        '</span> sec </div>';
                    $(elementId).html(temp);

                   if ((h == 0 && m == 0 && s == 0) || (s < 0)) {
                      clearInterval(timer);

                }, interval);
            }
       }
```

Comment: The exit condition about "ORDER EXPIRED" and the clearInterval is badly missing in your suggestion. You could improve that. Moment is a good thing to use... But OP script can also be debugged.

Comment: As per your suggestion code for clearInterval added. If it helpful, you can give upvote. :)

Comment: You should test your solutions... There.s a missing `}` for the last `if`. That fixed, the console shows `Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format.`.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I have a problem with this solution again. after uploading to the server the timer is adding 24hrs if the the time if over 12hrs and if the time is below 12hrs the counter count in 4seconds not 1second

Comment: mmm Strange enought. You should post your actual code in a new question.