# Passing simple php date variable to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, datetime

I have this php:

```
<?php
$mytestdate = "Oct 23, 2019 20:00:00";
?>
```

This javascript does not give me the required output:

```
<script>
var mydate = "<?php echo $mytestdate; ?>";
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date(mydate).getTime();
</script>
```

This javascript does give me the desired output:

```
<script>
var mydate = "<?php echo $mytestdate; ?>";
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Oct 23, 2019 20:00:00").getTime();
</script>
```

What is going wrong?!

The output is either nothing or "NaNd NaNh NaNm NaNs".

Comment: you should **never** mix PHP and JS  - they're different languages that get executed differently

Comment: what does your (html) source reveal?

Comment: try ```console.log(mydate)``` and see what is in there first, from there, you can know what's going wrong

Comment: From where does your mytestdate  comes from

Comment: what is your desired output. as both of them working

Comment: The output is either nothing or "NaNd NaNh NaNm NaNs"...

Comment: which browser are you using ???

Comment: i hope this will help u: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46109832/countdown-timer-php-javascript

Comment: I am using the Chrome browser

Comment: i am also using google chrome and both examples giving me timestamp value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So when you try to run this code in a HTML file you get `NaN` as you are claiming,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <?php
   $mytestdate = "Oct 23, 2019 20:00:00";
  ?>
<script>
  var mydate = "<?php echo $mytestdate; ?>";
  var countDownDate = new Date(mydate).getTime();
  alert(countDownDate);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Now, try to **save this in a file with `.php` extension**. The code will work and return you the expected result

Comment: <script>
var mydate = "<?php echo $mytestdate; ?>";
console.log(mydate);
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date(mydate).getTime();</script>

Comment: This is what is showing in the browser source. It does not seem to output the php.

Comment: @NeilReardon: so it means, your file extension is .PHP not .HTML right?

Comment: Yeah, that is what I am pointing. you have saved the file something as abc.html
, Remember PHP is a server side language and should be saved in a file for eg. abc.php

Comment: I am doing it all in Wordpress. The php code is in a plugin called "PHP Insert" and the javascript is in the page (Visual Composer).

Comment: If I put the date in then is works ok. I just cannot pass the variable (which I am reading from a mysql database).

Comment: <script>
var mydate = "Oct 23, 2019 20:00:00";
console.log(mydate);
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date(mydate).getTime();</script>

Comment: store your variable in a hidden input then get this hidden input value in your javascript @NeilReardon

Comment: @BilalSiddiqui: i like your answer ...

Comment: Thank you. I will do some research on hidden inputs now.